# Compiling c-extension from cython, "bad reloc address 0x0 in section `.data'" , "Python.h: No such file or directory"

Tags: windows, compiler-errors, mingw, cython, python-3.6

I have written a code in MATLAB for a project in school *(Pott's model in 3D for q = 3 states)*, that took to long to simulate, and rewrote my code in Python. The code was marginally faster but not fast enough, so I was thinking I could speed it up converting my Python file to C using Cython. Now before you ask, I know that Matlab has an inbuilt app for c-conversion of Matlab code, but I don't get it to work.

I am using:
- Windows 10
- Python 3.6
- Cython 0.25.2
- MinGW as gcc

According to  [Cython basic tutorial](http://docs.cython.org/en/latest/src/tutorial/cython_tutorial.html)

I need a setup.py file, so I have made one in the same folder as my main.py file and it looks like this:

```
from distutils.core import setup
from Cython.Build import cythonize

setup(
    ext_modules = cythonize("main.pyx")
)
```

From the same tutorial it says to save the .py file to .pyx and then write this line in Anaconda prompt:

```
python setup.py build_ext --inplace
```

Doing this, a "main.c"-file is produced, and it is at this point where it gets ugly. I am a real novice to the language c, but I try to compile this c-file in CMD to get an executable to run my program.

I first tried to type this in CMD:

```
gcc main.c
```

Which gave me the message:

```
main.c:11:20: fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory
 #include "Python.h"
                    ^
compilation terminated.
```

From this part, I also included the path to where python.h amongst other necessary files were (I also tried to include the path to my system variable PATH, hoping to not have to type in the path every time I try to compile, without succeeding... )

So this is what I am typing now instead:

```
C:\Users\burke\OneDrive\Spyder\F7035T>gcc -I C:\Users\burke\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\include main.c
```

From that, the output from the CMD where hundred of lines of undefined references, so I only include the last rows, so you get the picture of it:

```
C:\Users\burke\AppData\Local\Temp\cc5gCfUu.o:main.c:(.text+0x32469): undefined reference to `__imp__Py_NoneStruct'
C:\Users\burke\AppData\Local\Temp\cc5gCfUu.o:main.c:(.text+0x32489): undefined reference to `__imp_PyObject_IsTrue'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.8.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\burke\AppData\Local\Temp\cc5gCfUu.o: bad reloc address 0x0 in section `.data'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

At this point, I no longer know what to do. I have tried to google it without any good result. I hope someone can help me with this problem. Sorry for my English, I'm from Sweden.

/Johan

Comment: The `python setup.py build_ext --inplace` should produce a `main.pyd` file (it's fine if it also produces `main.c`). Do you get the pyd file? If you do then you're done and you don't need to run gcc yourself.

Comment: (You use the `pyd` file by doing `import main` in Python)

Comment: Yes it produced a file named:
main.cp36-win_amd64.pyd and also a folder containing one .exp file, one .lib file and one .obj file.

I thought i would get an .exe file to run?

Comment: The main.cp36-win_amd64.pyd file looks corrupted when I open it with a text editor.

Comment: It looks like it's worked. You get a pyd file which you can import as a python module. It is not a text file so it's expected to look odd in a text editor. There are ways of producing an exe file with Cython but it isn't really that useful (you usually need to distribute a lot of other Python files with for it to work).

Comment: Okey, forgive me for asking silly questions, but am I supposed to make a .c-file where I import this .pyd file?

Otherwise, I don't think I understand how I should run this python converted files in order to get a up speeded version of the Python file.

Comment: To go back to the beginning: when your run setup.py it generates a .c file from your .pyx file. It then compiles that .c file to a .pyd file (so the .pyd file contains the code you wrote, but hopefully faster). You then use Python to import the .pyd file like a normal Python module. So in a normal Python interpreter you type `import main`. At that point any code that is outside a function is run. If you want to run one of your compiled functions you type `main.your_function_name()`.

Comment: Okey, DavidW, I think I got it now. Thank you for your patience!

Comment: No problem! (I've voted to close the question as "can no longer be reproduced" since I think it was mostly a misunderstanding and I'm not sure the question would be edited to make it useful to people having similar issues.)